# How to remove contact us form loaded in iframe from html page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

After searching lot and trying 5-6 demos but none of working for what i want.
I have service page that showing service of other domain(Website) as iframe
and below that iframe i have my contact us form, but my issue is that iframe page also contain contact us page.that i want to remove.

is it possible to remove form that loading from iframe source?

Edit: MY Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function remove_elemment() {
    var form = document.forms;


        form.style.display = "none";

    }
};

function doRemove() {
    document.frame.document.getElementById('my_iframe').remove_elemment();
}();

</script>
<div class="floating-widget">
    <iframe id="my_iframe" src="http://192.168.0.104/wordpress/?p=1" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="800">             
    </iframe>

</div>
```

and comment form loaded in html is as below

```
<div id="respond" class="comment-respond">
   <h3 id="reply-title" class="comment-reply-title">Leave a Reply <small><a rel="nofollow" id="cancel-comment-reply-link" href="/wordpress/?p=1#respond" style="display:none;">Cancel reply</a></small></h3>
   <form action="http://192.168.0.104/wordpress/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="commentform" class="comment-form" novalidate="">
      <p class="comment-notes"><span id="email-notes">Your email address will not be published.</span> Required fields are marked <span class="required">*</span></p>
      <p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">Comment</label> <textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" maxlength="65525" aria-required="true" required="required"></textarea></p>
      <p class="comment-form-author"><label for="author">Name <span class="required">*</span></label> <input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="" size="30" maxlength="245" aria-required="true" required="required"></p>
      <p class="comment-form-email"><label for="email">Email <span class="required">*</span></label> <input id="email" name="email" type="email" value="" size="30" maxlength="100" aria-describedby="email-notes" aria-required="true" required="required"></p>
      <p class="comment-form-url"><label for="url">Website</label> <input id="url" name="url" type="url" value="" size="30" maxlength="200"></p>
      <p class="form-submit"><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class="submit" value="Post Comment"> <input type="hidden" name="comment_post_ID" value="1" id="comment_post_ID">
         <input type="hidden" name="comment_parent" id="comment_parent" value="0">
      </p>
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Put your html also

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21502681/remove-elements-within-an-iframe

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
$('#MainPopupIframe').on('load', function(){
    $(this).contents().find("#formOrButtonToRemove").Remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `iframe` source (the service page) is not from the same domain and not using the same protocol as your page , then it will not work because of same-origin policy. But if your page is in same domain and using same protocol, then you can use this to remove contact form. `$("#iframeId").contents().find("#contactformdiv").remove();`